# How to wait for a slightly longer scheduler process to finish, while doing e2e testing

Tags: cypress

How to wait for a slightly longer scheduler process to finish, while doing e2e testing

Hi,

I am automating an E2E scenario, where we put a request for report generation from web-UI.
The workflow is such that, after we click on Submit button for report generation.

A non-blocking process start to run & in min or so it adds a new  in the results table below.

How to wait for such Event (i.e. for the record to get generated on top of existing records stack)?
I would like to avoid arbitrary `wait(400)` etc.
Bear in mind there might already be few rows in the table, where new row gets generated on top of existing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> it adds a new in the results table below

If you expect the DOM to eventually update as a result of this request, you can simply add a larger timeout to a Cypress assertion:

for example, waiting (up to 60s) for the results table to have over 100 `li` elements:

```js
// something happens
cy.get('.results-table', {timeout: 60000}).should(($table) => {
  expect($table.children().length).to.be.gt(100)
})
// continue test, or timeout after 60s
```

Comment: And to avoid extending the timeout globally, you should extend it for just this operation.

     cy.get('.results-table', { timeout: 99999999 } ).should(($table) => {
         expect($table.children().length).to.be.gt(100)
     })


See [the cypress docs on timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Example-3-Modifying-Timeouts)

Comment: Our table rows are getting dynamically populated. Also it has pagination. So how to handle it, in this case? Thanks

Comment: See my example, you wait for more than n rows to be populated.